# loop for change button value when clicked

Tags: android, loops, android-studio, kotlin

i'm trying to use a loop to change the value of my button, but when i run the app and click in the button, he just changes one time and the button stucks, like it's not reseting the button when gets to the last value.

There are only 3 options in the button (Normal, Repeating, Shuffle)

It may be a completely dumb question, but i really don't know what i can do.

```
var repMode = 0

        binding.btnRepMode.setOnClickListener {
            do{
                repMode++
            }while(repMode < 2)

            when(repMode){
                0 -> normalRep()
                1 -> repeatRep()
                2 -> shuffleRep()
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is it meant to do? From the user's perspective I mean. If you want it to do a different thing each time it's clicked (so first click calls `normalRep()`, next one calls `repeatRep()`) that's easy enough. But if you want one button click to start a sequence that runs on its own that's a bit more complex. Your code's "sticking" right now because your `do/while` increments `repMode` to `2` (and does nothing else, so it's basically the same as `repMode = 2`) and then you call `shuffleRep`. Next time you click the button it adds `1` to `repMode`, exits the `while`, and then nothing matches `3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that doing

```kotlin
do {
  repMode++
} while (repMode < 2)
```

does what you think it does. A `do-while` loop will run repeatedly until the `while` condition is no longer true. This means it will keep incrementing `repMode` until it reaches 2, then stop. It's not clear if you want it to stop when it gets to 2, or start over.

**Stopping at 2 (0-1-2-2-2-2-2...)**

If you want to increment `repMode` but not allow it to be greater than 2 you could use something like this instead

```kotlin
if( repMode < 2 ) {
  ++repMode
}
```

or

```kotlin
repMode = (++repMode).coerceAtMost(2)
```

**Starting over (0-1-2-0-1-2-...)**

If you want `repMode` to have a repeating cycle (0-1-2-0-1-2...) rather than getting stuck at "2" then you could use a modulus operator (`%`) like this:

```kotlin
repMode = (++repMode) % 3
```

You can test the original code out in a simple unit test very easily in Android Studio - the result is always 2. I highly recommend using small tests and log/print statements to help you solve problems like this when you encounter them.

```kotlin
@Test
fun testDoWhile() {
    var repMode = 0
    do {
        repMode++
    } while (repMode < 2)

    println("TEST repMode = $repMode")
}
```

Comment: yeah, i wanted to make it start over than get stuck at 2. I thought that i had to use a loop to make it work as i intended to. I understanded how it works now, thank you man.

and thanks for the tip, i will certainly use it.